# multithreading does not work with launch::async option

Tags: c++, multithreading

I would like to run a program simultaneously with different parameters. For this, I wrote another program in C++.

I perform the threading with this code:

```
 future<double> fut[REPEAT];
 for (int j = 0; j < REPEAT; j++) {
      fut[j] = async(launch::async, executerCallerTask, currentWeight, j);
 }
```

while the executerCallerTask calls a class

```
double executerCallerTask(double currentWeight, int threadNo){
    cout << "a new thread started!!!!" << endl << endl << endl;
    anExecuter instance(currentWeight, ITERATIONS, threadNo);
    double var1 = instance.getVar1();
    return var1;
}
```

This class basically runs the program with the given parameters

```
anExecuter::anExecuter(double currentWeight, int iterations, int threadNo){
    char commandString[120];
    snprintf(commandString,120,"cd /Program Directory/; ./program %f %d",currentWeight, iterations);
    system(commandString);
}
```

The problem here is the programs with different parameters run one after the other, not at the same time. I also tried an alternative solution using `thread(executerCallerTask, currentWeight, j);` but couldn't get it to work either.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT

Following Lightness Races in Orbit's warning, I set up breakpoints and saw that threading works until it comes to line `system(commandString);`. I think the wait is because `system` only works on one terminal and calls the commands one by one. So probably nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: _"the programs with different parameters run one after the other, not at the same time"_ How do you know?

Comment: From the output generated by the called program. Also, a part of the anExecuter class writes to file the result of the called program which updates every 5 minutes (length of running of the called program) and by looking at the activity monitor.

Comment: I don't see how any of that counts as admissible evidence.

Comment: What is the correct way to check?

Comment: I don't think that you should. You're making gross assumptions about the way your OS will allocate time slices to each thread. It's completely valid for the first to execute quick enough to be done before the second even starts. `std::async` doesn't guarantee any particular level of execution interleaving; it just guarantees that the library _won't_ block starting of the second on completion of the first.